# spurious lines using fimplicit on a modular function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot collections of repeating circular arcs and am having trouble with spurious lines showing up in the plots. For example, one of the plots I want is given by

```
a = @(x,y) ((mod(x,1) + 0.5).^2 + (mod(y,1) - 0.5).^2 - 1)
fimplicit(a,[-1,1],'MeshDensity',500)
```

but the output is incorrect as far as I can tell:[image]

The implicit function is decidedly not zero on the verticle lines. I assume something funny is happening with the fimplicit algorithm and modular arithmetic. Any ideas how to get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably happens because your function is **discontinuous** at the lines *x* = *k* with *k* integer, as a surface plot reveals:

```
fsurf(a, [-2 2])
```

[image]

To verify that the discontinuity is the likely reason, consider the simpler **example**

```
f = @(x,y) (2*(x>=0)-1).*(2*(y>=0)-1);
```

This function is discontinuous at *x* = 0 and at *y* = 0. It jumps from 1 to −1 at *x* = 0 and at *y* = 0, but it never equals 0.

```
fsurf(f, [-2 2])
```

[image]

It can be seen that `fimplicit` is confused by the discontinuity, and thinks the function is `0` there:

```
fimplicit(f,[-2,2],'MeshDensity',500)
```

[image]

Looking at the **source code** of `fimplicit`, the actual work is seen to be done (on R2017b at least) by the class `matlab.graphics.function.ImplicitFunctionLine` in the second to last line. That class is a `.p` file, and is thus **obfuscated**, which means that unfortunately its source code cannot be seen.